# NFS stops responding after connecting to NordVPN

Tags: networking, nfs

This problem started a few days ago after an upgrade.  At the time I was running 18.04 when the problem started.  In case the latest ubuntu version fixed the problem, I upgraded to 20.04 but the problem persists.

After doing a "nordvpn connect", I am receiving the message "filesystem not responding" and my NFS shares are identified.  From that point on, the only application the will respond is the terminal window in which the "connect" was made from.  If there is another application open, it will only respond after a disconnect is done.

In case it was the nordvpn program itself, I removed it and re-installed as per the instructions at nordvpn.com but to no change.  Contacted the Nordvpn Helpdesk and they had me flush the firewall cache and still the same problem.

Before running the "nordvpn connect" or after doing a "nordvpn disconnect", I can run other programs without issue and reach the NFS filesystems without a problem.

What have I missed?

The NFS server is 192.168.0.51 and the VM machine connecting to the NFS shares is 192.168.0.81 (before the nordvpn connect) then it receives a 10. address after the "connect". Could the change in IP be causing the problem?

Comment: What is the IP address of the NFS server you're connecting to and what is the IP address of your local machine?

Comment: Thank you user68186.  Adding the whitelist appears to have addressed the problem.  Since it was working prior to the update without the whitelist, I hadn't even thought of adding it.

Comment: Yes - answer is correct.

Comment: I have converted my comment to an answer. If you think the answers below is correct, accept that answer by clicking on the gray check mark ✔next to it and turn it green ✅. This will indicate that the answer is correct and help others with the same problem. You can also up-vote my answer to show your appreciation.

Comment: I am having a similar issue causing a system freeze when connected to NordVPN and accessing a NFS share. Since this problem first appeared after an upgrade of the NordVPN app, I contacted NordVPN support. I personally view whitelisting as a workaround, not a solution. This issue causes users considerable inconvenience in the form of multiple reboots and looking for a solution. This requires a dev-side fix or an confirmation that it cannot be fixed for some reason. @phild do you happen to know the version of the NordVPN app you were running that did NOT have this issue before you upgraded?

Comment: I don't know the exact version - I created the VM in the June/July timeframe and installed nordvpn at that time so that would have been the version I was using before doing the upgrade.  Sorry can't be of more assistance.

Comment: You'll have the same issue with SSHFS mounts to a local network. If you have active SSHFS mounts and then connect to VPN, Ubuntu becomes completely unresponsive. The accepted answer solves this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Whitelist your local network in NordVPN

NordVPN has a whitelist option that can whitelist ports as well as IP address ranges. Try the command:

```
nordvpn whitelist add subnet 192.168.0.0/16
```

or alternately a more restrictive version should also work if your local network only consists of IP addresses in the ranges `192.168.0.xyz`, where `xyz` is a number between 1-255.

```
nordvpn whitelist add subnet 192.168.0.0/24
```

See NordVPN's [support page](https://support.nordvpn.com/Connectivity/Linux/1325531132/Installing-and-using-NordVPN-on-Debian-Ubuntu-Elementary-OS-and-Linux-Mint.htm) for more information.